# Drive encryption not avaliable in Windows 11 Home: Test Interface failed and device is not Modern Standby

Tags: encryption, windows-11

I'm trying to encrypt a drive on mine laptop. I had this error:
Un-allowed DMA capable bus/device(s) detected

So I followed the steps described in [This comment](https://superuser.com/a/1589473)
Now I'm getting new, but less informative errors:

```
Device Encryption Support   Reasons for failed automatic device encryption: Hardware Security Test Interface failed and device is not Modern Standby
```

How can I debug this? What else could be wrong?
Regards

Comment: Please read section "Platform requirements for modern standby" https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/platform-design-for-modern-standby

Comment: Thanks, so my device is just not compatible

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1537206/does-home-edition-of-windows-10-encrypt-files/1537324#1537324) previous question has an answer that lists the requirements for Device Encryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message means that your device is indeed incompatible and doesn't
support Device Encryption.

As a replacement, you could use the free and open-source
[VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html).